# strftime not displaying current date

Tags: php, timestamp, locale, strftime

If I use

```
$end_date_formatted = date("F d, Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month_end, $day_end, $year_end));
```

it returns correct date based on values of $month_end, $day_end, $year_end.

But if I use

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR');
$end_date_formatted = utf8_encode(strftime("%d %B %G", mktime(0, 0, 0, $day_end, $month_end, $year_end)))
```

A completely diferent date is returned.It shows 12 février 2015, it should display 26 Decembre 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mktime(0, 0, 0, $month_end, $day_end, $year_end)))
```

vs

```
mktime(0, 0, 0, $day_end, $month_end, $year_end)))
```

In one you are getting the 12th month, in one the 12th day.  In the other you are getting the 26th month (so it's adding some years), in the other the 26th day.

That's the issue.